# Prove that $S^k$ is a subgroup of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> For a non empty set $S$ of a group $G$,define $$S^k=\{\Pi_{i=1} ^{n} s_i |  s_i \in S\}$$ for any positive integer $k$. Prove that, if $G$ has $n$ elements, then $S^n$ is a subgroup of $G$.

I am a beginner in abstract algebra so couldn’t achieve something that I could discuss

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: what is the definition of a subgroup?

Comment: I don’t even know how to approach this one...

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup

Comment: how does the elemnts in $S^k$ look like?

Comment: I have exactly quoted the statement from a book ... noting else is given

Comment: I understand that but I asked you not the book

Comment: $s_1 s_2 s_3 \cdots$

Comment: Refer MODERN ALGEBRA by Sujeet Singh  page 80

Comment: This is not an easy question for a beginnier.